# bash If statement failing

Tags: bash, if-statement, curl, ftp

Im working on a bash script to check an ftp site to see if some files exist on it. It works by looping through an array of files using curl to check if the file exists on the ftp server. If it doesnt then curl should output an error which im looking for in my if loop and echoing a result based on it. Code below:

```
#!/bin/bash

# script variables
ftpaddress=ftpaddress
ftplocation=folderlocation
ftpusername=ftpusername
ftppassword=ftppassword
err="curl: (19) Given file does not exist"

# Initialise array of files
files=( "file1.xml" "file2.xml" "zy.xml" )

for f in "${files[@]}"; do
     result=(curl ftp://$ftpaddress$ftplocation$f --user $ftpusername:$ftppassword --head)
     if [[ "$result" == "$err" ]]; then 
          echo $f " Does not exist!!!!"
     else
          echo $f "Exists"
     fi 
done
```

Something about the if loop is failing, ive tried lots of variations on it but have been unable to find one that works. At the moment the result is never matching the error. When I run the curl just from the command line it outputs the error i have set to `$err` if the file doesnt exist but when running the script the else branch is being selected everytime saying the file does exist. I've even tried setting the error to be`*"19"*`and it still doesnt match. I've spent a lot of time looking it up and testing it but have had no luck so would appreciate any help that can be given.

Thanks

Comment: seriously use wget instead of curl, wget returns a error state (in $?) if it fails.

Comment: your echo statements should have $f inside the quotes, just in-case the filename starts with `-e ` or `-n ` etc... in general "$" used anywhere outside of quote marks is an invitation for a shell injection attack.

Comment: @Jasen Quotes aren't going to help with arguments on its own. `echo "-n" foo` still treats `-n` as an argument. It does help if the variable is `-n something` though by avoiding word-splitting.

Comment: oops should have spotted that, many thanks Jasen. I'll take a look at using wget instead.

Comment: @EtanReisner quote everything after echo in one lump: `echo "-n foo"`

Comment: @Jasen Yes, I did mention that (though obliquely) in my comment. My point was that quotes aren't the solution to the argument parsing problem as-such. They happen to work on some strings that would otherwise go wrong but not all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`( )`  will get you the return value  `$( )` will get you stdout

```
 result=$(curl ftp://$ftpaddress$ftplocation$f --user $ftpusername:$ftppassword --head 2>&1)
```